# knockout.js data-bind style with border-radius

Tags: javascript, css, data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to apply border-radius css attribute using knockout.js data-bind attribute:

```
data-bind="style: { width: totalLength() < workDay ? totalLength() + 'px' : workDay + 'px', border-radius: '10px', background: '#a9fd76' }"
```

but the browser doesn't seem to like it at all. I get an error from `knockout.js` file saying:

> "Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: SyntaxError: missing :
>   after property id; Bindings value: style: { width: totalLength() <
>   workDay ? totalLength() + 'px' : workDay + 'px', border-radius:
>   '10px', background: '#a9fd76' }"

Does it mean that CSS3 attributes are not supported by knockout.js bindings?

Just to mention everything works fine when I take border-radius attribute out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write it as:

```
borderRadius
```

as border-radius is not a valid javascript name.

You can see more examples at the bottom of the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) on it.

Comment: @Bartosz No problem! Nothing says thanks like an upvote and marking the answer correct though. :)